# Multiple Dropdown in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to select multiple dropdown values in react js using Dynamic Values.

```
<Col lg="10">
    <select id="facility_id" className="form-control select2" value={this.state.facility_id} onChange={this.handleChange} title="Type Growing system" isMulti>
       <option value="0">None</option>
       {this.state.facilities.map((faci, key) =>
       <option key={key} value={faci.facility_id}>{faci.facility_name}</option>
       )}

    </select>
```

react-select is not working for me . Any other options available?

Answer (score 0):

Use element attr `multiple` instead of `isMulti`.
Try something like this.

```js
const Select = () => {
  const [selections, setSelections] = React.useState(['b', 'c']);
  
  const onSeletionChange = val => {
    let sels = [...selections];
    if (sels.includes(val)) {
      sels = sels.filter(x => x !== val);
    } else {
      sels.push(val);
    }
    setSelections(sels);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Multi Select (select again to remove)  
      
      <select
        id="facility_id"
        className="form-control select2"
        value={selections}
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log(e.target.value);
          onSeletionChange(e.target.value);
        }}
        title="Type Growing system"
        multiple
      >
        <option value="0" key="0">None</option>
        {["a", "b", "c"].map((faci, key) => (
          <option key={key} value={faci}>
            {faci}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
ReactDOM.render(<Select />, domContainer);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"> </div>
```